# Set blank result equal to specific string in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that returns a result set which contains a certain column that needs some tweaking. Basically, in the result set, there are certain rows that contain a blank value for the applicable column. What I need to do is set all instances of that blank value to a specific string. I have tried declaring a variable and setting the variable equal to the column name (using a SELECT statement) and then using an IF statement to set the value to a specific string if it is blank (' '). My code thus far is as follows:

```
declare @sourceNode varchar(30)                  
set @sourceNode = (select sn_name from pt_cust)
if @sourceNode = '' begin
    set @sourceNode = 'None'
end
```

This code returns an error stating that the sub-query returns more than 1 value. This seems like an easy task but I am stuck at the moment. How can this be accomplished?

Comment: Did you try `isnull()`?

Comment: @Aishvarya - I think the value is not null, but a blank string ('') - so ISNULL() would not work.

Answer (score 0):

This is a case (heh) for CASE:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN sn_name = '' THEN 'None' ELSE sn_name END
FROM pt_cust
```

You are getting the error message you mentioned because your SELECT statement can return more than one row, in which case it can not be assigned to a variable.

Comment: You're answer is correct; however, could edit it to address this statement in the question?: "This code returns an error stating that the subquery returns more than 1 value." This is due to the subquery returning multiple results to a VARCHAR variable.

Comment: @Amirreza I did not ridicule the question, nor did I intent to. Pun intended.

Comment: @Amirreza Keshavarz: As already mentioned, it's called a pun. A pun is a completely harmless form of word play. In no way is a pun meant to be ridiculous, judgmental or offensive, and you should not have reported it as such.